# Is it possible to search within my questions

Tags: support

Currently searching on a certain criteria gives us results from the whole website. Is there a facility to search within my question and answers? There might be a situation where I would like to refer my previous questions or answers. But its not easy to go on each page and check them one by one. Is there a short cut?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yup! The easiest way is to click on your profile and then do a search. The search box is auto-populated with `user:2070` where 2070 would be your user id.

If I wanted to search all of my questions that included SPGridView: `user:2070 spgridview`

See also, [the search tips](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/search).